# Select all objects with font-size between two sizes in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to select all text-objects with a size between two values, for example 12 and 14pt (including 12.1, 12.2 etc). Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be the candidate for a script. Try this:

```js
function selectTextWhosePointSizeIs ( minPointSize, maxPointSize )
{
    var doc, tfs, i = 0, n = 0, selectionArray = [];

    if ( !app.documents.length ) { return; }

    doc = app.activeDocument;
    tfs = doc.textFrames;
    n = tfs.length;

    if ( !n ){ return; }

    if ( isNaN ( minPointSize ) )
    {
        alert(minPointSize + " is not a valid number" );
        return;
    }
    else if ( isNaN ( maxPointSize ) )
    {
        alert(maxPointSize + " is not a valid number" );
        return;
    }
    else if ( minPointSize > maxPointSize )
    {
        alert(minPointSize + " can't be greater than "+ maxPointSize);
        return;
    }

    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
        if ( tfs[i].textRange.size >= minPointSize && tfs[i].textRange.size <= maxPointSize )
        {
            selectionArray [ selectionArray.length ] = tfs[i];
        }
    }

    if ( selectionArray.length )
    {
        app.selection = selectionArray;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Nothing found in this range.");
    }
}

selectTextWhosePointSizeIs ( 12, 14 );
```

Hope it helps,

Loic